# How to download the .ipa for MDM?

Tags: ios-appstore, mobile-device-management

We use Apple MDM at the small school I work at to manage our iPads.  In the past we would download the .ipa from the App Store then upload it to the MDM then deploy it to the iPads.  With the new updates we can't figure out a way to download the .ipa files?  Can anyone help?  (I will add we are not in the US and do not have access to VPP.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on the MDM or are you just looking for the link to get iTunes version to get the IPA so you can then manage your devices:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079

Comment: We are using Apple Configurator 2 for the MDM.  I think with Apple Configurator 2 we have to have the IPA file to use on our devices.  Do you know of any work arounds?

Comment: Use iTunes per the link @SarahC